# Message body writer error while doing POST operation with JSON payload using Jersey Client

Tags: json, jersey, mime

e I am trying to do a POST operation with JSON payload for REST service using Jersey Client in JUnit . 
Here is what I have done:

Resource Class

```
@Path("/Users")
@Component
public class UserResource{
@POST
@Path("register")
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String registerUser(RegisterRequestJSON requestJson)
{
         User user = userManager.getUserInformationByEmail(email);
        UserInfoJSON userInfoJSON = new UserInfoJSON();
        userInfoJSON.copyFromUserBean(user);
        GoodResponseObject gro = new GoodResponseObject(Status.OK.getStatusCode(), Status.OK.getReasonPhrase(), userInfoJSON);
        try {
            return Formatter.getAsJson(gro, true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new WebApplicationException(Response.status(Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity(e).build());
        } 
      }
  }
```

Resource Test

```
String registerUserUrl = "http://localhost:9998/Users/Path";
    JSONObject inputJsonObj = new JSONObject();
    inputJsonObj.put("accessToken", userAccessToken );
    inputJsonObj.put("accessTokenType", "example" );
    ClientConfig clientConfigRegisterUser = new DefaultClientConfig();
    clientConfigRegisterUser.getFeatures().put(JSONConfiguration.FEATURE_POJO_MAPPING,Boolean.TRUE);
    Client clientRegisterUser = Client.create(clientConfigRegisterUser);
    WebResource registerUser = clientRegisterUser.resource(registerUserUrl); 
    String registerResponse = registerUser.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).post(String.class,registerJson);
```

When I run the test , I get the below error:

```
com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: A message body writer for Java type, class com.genie.account.mgmt.json.RegisterRequestJSON, and MIME media type, application/json, was not found
at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:151)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:648)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:680)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.post(WebResource.java:568)
at com.genie.account.mgmt.resources.UserResourceTest.testGetUserInformationByEmail(UserResourceTest.java:97)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:30)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: A message body writer for Java type, class com.genie.account.mgmt.json.RegisterRequestJSON, and MIME media type, application/json, was not found
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.RequestWriter.writeRequestEntity(RequestWriter.java:288)
at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler._invoke(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:213)
at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:149)
```

What could be the issue here ?

Comment: First you just get rid of @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON}) this and replace this with @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) annotation.

Answer (score 0):

Your client is not capable of know how to serialize (write) the com.genie.account.mgmt.json.RegisterRequestJSONparameter in order to send it to the REST end point.

By default Jersey try using JAXB for serializing to JSON/XML but your RegisterRequestJSONparameter type should be annotated

Another option is to use custom writers / readers as stated in this answer:

[In Jersey, how do I make some methods use the POJO mapping feature and some not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16801174/in-jersey-how-do-i-make-some-methods-use-the-pojo-mapping-feature-and-some-not/16812152#16812152)

Comment: This error got resolved after adding the @XmlRootElement(name = "RegisterRequestJSON") annotation in JSON class. Thanks a lot !