# ClientHandlerException, Message Body Writer mime media type application/json

Tags: web-services, jakarta-ee

I added a new Webservice to my code. For which I had to add a new Concrete Data POJO set.

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import com.swipex.common.authenticator.IAuthenticable;

public class CServiceCenterOwnerDetails implements IServiceCenterOwnerDetails,
        IServiceCenterOwnerDetailsSetters, IAuthenticable, Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
```

Exception I got was

```
com.sun.jersey.api.client.clienthandlerexception: a message body writer for java type, class , and mime media type, application/json, was not found at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.urlconnectionclienthandler.handle
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I had to do was to add a annotation `@XmlRootElement` to the class definition, and it worked.

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import com.swipex.common.authenticator.IAuthenticable;

@XmlRootElement
public class CServiceCenterOwnerDetails implements IServiceCenterOwnerDetails,
        IServiceCenterOwnerDetailsSetters, IAuthenticable, Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
```

Reference to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16844303/message-body-writer-error-while-doing-post-operation-with-json-payload-using-jer) answer, even though it did not point me to the perfect solution to my problem, it did have a hint.

Comment: `@XmlRootElement` worked for me but I'm not sure why :-)